# How to make a java hashmap containing list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, dictionary, hashmap

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import mainak.faisal;
import mainak.pulkit;

public class StartingPoint {

    public static void main( String trav[] ) {
        final Map<String, List<String>> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list1.add("1");
        paramMap.put("segment", list1);
        list1.clear();
        list1.add("2");
        paramMap.put("subDepartment", list1);
        list1.clear();
        list1.add("3");
        paramMap.put("officerTitle", list1);

        for( Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : paramMap.entrySet() ) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println("ACTIONKEY"+"------"+key);

            for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println("ACTIONVALUE-----"+value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
ACTIONKEY------segment
ACTIONVALUE-----1
ACTIONKEY------subDepartment
ACTIONVALUE-----2
ACTIONKEY------officerTitle
ACTIONVALUE-----3
```

But its showing :

```
ACTIONKEY------segment
ACTIONVALUE-----3
ACTIONKEY------subDepartment
ACTIONVALUE-----3
ACTIONKEY------officerTitle
ACTIONVALUE-----3
```

Why this is happening? How can I achieve the desired result without making different lists?

Comment: The value is same for all 3 keys (i.e. it is `list1`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want 3 different lists in your map, then you need to create 3 lists. Creating only one list will cause the map to contain 3 references to the same list, containing what you stored in the list at the last step:

```
segment ---------
                 \
subDepartment----  [3]
                 /
officerTitle ----
```

What you want is

```
segment --------- [1]

subDepartment---- [2]

officerTitle ---- [3]
```

So you need 3 different lists. Understand that putting a list in a map doesn't create a copy of the list. It only stores a reference (a pointer, if you prefer) to the list passed as argument.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a list before putting in HashMap,

```
   public static void main(String trav[]){
        final Map<String, List<String>> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
        paramMap.put("segment", Lists.newArrayList("1"));
        paramMap.put("subDepartment", Lists.newArrayList("2"));
        paramMap.put("officerTitle", Lists.newArrayList("3"));
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : paramMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println("ACTIONKEY"+"------"+key);
            for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println("ACTIONVALUE-----"+value);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you create and clear list1? Is Guava really necessary to create lists? The OP doesn't use Guava.

Comment: But you're still using Guava.

Comment: @JBNizet I have Used Guava for less code. yes i agree that OP does not using Guava library but let him explore to this way of creating the list and adding the values to the list in one step..

Answer (score 2):

While you pass objects in java you pass actually the reference of that object and all the items you add point to the same list object as **JB Nizet** explained in his answer . Following are the things you can do :

1. Create a new list each time an add it to the Hashmap object.
2. Use Google Guava Collections like :

   ```
    Multimap<String, String> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    // put values into map for segment

    multiMap.put("segment", "1");
    multiMap.put("segment", "100");

    // put values into map for subDepartment

    multiMap.put("subDepartment", "2");
    multiMap.put("subDepartment", "200");

    // put values into map for officerTitle

    multiMap.put("officerTitle", "3");
    multiMap.put("officerTitle", "300");
   ```
3. Or Use Apache Commons Collection like :

   ```
    // create multimap to store key and values

    MultiMap multiMap = new MultiValueMap();

    // put values into map for segment

    multiMap.put("segment", "1");
    multiMap.put("segment", "100");

    // put values into map for subDepartment

    multiMap.put("subDepartment", "2");
    multiMap.put("subDepartment", "200");

    // put values into map for officerTitle

    multiMap.put("officerTitle", "3");
    multiMap.put("officerTitle", "300");
   ```

All will give you correct output. !

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are referencing only one instance of List object to the HashMap.

When the reference to the List change the Values of the HashMap changes.

In your situation

```
    list1.add("1");
    paramMap.put("segment", list1);
    list1.clear();
    list1.add("2");
    paramMap.put("subDepartment", list1);
    list1.clear();
    list1.add("3");
```

That last value you added to the list after you clear it will be the values of all the data in your `HashMap`

**solution:**

Create a new instance of List every time you add to the HashMap

Answer (score 1):

you can make every time new list and and and add value value to it and then you put in the map.

like this..

Map < String, List< String>> map = new HashMap< String, List< String>>();

```
    // create list one and store values
    List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    valSetOne.add("1");
    //valSetOne.add("Aeroplane");

    // create list two and store values
    List<String> valSetTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
    valSetTwo.add("2");
   // valSetTwo.add("Banana");

    // create list three and store values
    List<String> valSetThree = new ArrayList<String>();
    valSetThree.add("3");
    //valSetThree.add("Car");

    // put values into map
    map.put("A", valSetOne);
    map.put("B", valSetTwo);
    map.put("C", valSetThree);


    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<String> values = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Key = " + key);
        System.out.println("Values = " + values );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new list each time when you want to put in a map. It's because map is checking the reference of the list and you're inserting the list with same reference and map won't store duplicate keys so basically it updates the entry with the last given list value.